# Only one session is used in the telethone

Tags: python, telethon

I ran into a problem that telethon uses only one session to log in, even if I change api_id and api_hash. I don't understand how to fix it. I don't want to close sessions all the time, and I don't want to delete a file from sessions either.

```
api_id = int(input("Enter API ID: "))
api_hash = str(input("Enter API hash: "))

import telethon
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import random

client = TelegramClient('tagall_session', api_id, api_hash, system_version="4.16.30-vxCUSTOM")
client.start()


@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='!tagall'))
async def tag_all(event):
    if event.sender_id != (await client.get_me()).id:
        return

    chat = await event.get_chat()
    text = event.text.partition(' ')[2] if ' ' in event.text else 'Внимание всем!'
    participants = await event.client.get_participants(await event.get_chat())
    random.shuffle(participants)  # Случайным образом перемешиваем участников чата

    for i in range(0, len(participants), 100):
        mentions = ''.join(f'[\u180E](tg://user?id={m.id}) ' for m in participants[i:i + 100])
        await client.send_message(chat, f'{text} {mentions}')

    await event.delete()


client.run_until.disconnected()
```